# Subset selection, shrinkage and dimensionality reduction in regression analysis

Tags: regression, pca, lasso, dimensionality-reduction, regularization

I am currently reading *An Introduction to Statistical Learning: With Applications in R* by Robert Tibshirani and Trevor Hastie. I am confused about various regularization methods for linear regression, namely about subset selection, shrinkage methods and dimensionality reduction methods.

1. If a shrinkage method (LASSO regression) can be used for reducing the number of predictors, what is the advantage of subset selection methods?
2. Should subset selection be applied before using shrinkage methods?
3. Can shrinkage or subset selection be done after dimensionality reduction?

Comment: There is a whole variety of regularization approaches, and none of them is guaranteed to be better than the rest; there is no "free lunch" here. Any combination of approaches might happen to outperform the rest in a particular situation. So the answers are **(1) Not much; (2) It can; (3) Yes, it can.** That said, both subset selection methods and dimensionality reduction methods (such as PC regression) are usually considered to be inferior to shrinkage methods such as ridge and lasso. A combination of ridge and lasso called **elastic net** is a very common method of choice.

Comment: Hey @amoeba , this looks like it could be an answer with only a little more work. Do you want to write one?  (I'm trying to reduce the number of unanswered questions here)